# html/javascript "decimal-input" for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, input, cordova, decimal

im working on a (cordova) web-app with some input fields for decimals.
As well known there is no way to change the system keyboards within the browser, so im looking for an javascript (jQuery) plugin to do the magic with a numeric only keyboard.

I would like to have the following functionality, which should be provide the best usability for the user:

```
Typing | Result
1      | 0.01
12     | 0.12
123    | 1.23
1234   | 12.34
12345  | 123.45
123456 | 1,234.56
```

Ive found a plugin which does nearly exact what i described, with one exception: You type only in the full numbers, you have to type the decimal separator to change the decimals.

http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-number-format-redux/196/

Demo: http://opensource.teamdf.com/number/examples/demo-as-you-type.html

As i want to run it on a smartphone i would like to use `<input type="text" pattern="\d*" />`, so there is no way to input the decimal separator to that plugin.

I have done some searching, but found no plugin for that usage.
I really cant imagine no one has written such plugin before, so i am asking you:

**Is there a plugin to create a working decimal input on a web-app?**

Comment: What about `<input type=number>`? That will trigger the full numeric keyboard on a phone/tablet.

Comment: I would like to have a numeric-keyboard and `<input type="number" />` would give a "complete" keyboard on iOS. With the pattern-attribute i do get the numeric-only keyboard, but sadly just numeric, without a decimal separator.

Details: http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/05/triggering-numeric-keyboards-with-html5.html

Comment: If the decimal should be at a specific place you could use jquery masked input, but i guess that is not the case...?

Comment: In my case i always have 2 decimals, but unlimited integers.
With masked input i would have to define the integers before, which is not possible as some users may have "0.25" and others may have "9,999.00" as value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the jQuery Plugin "[meiomask](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/)" - which provides exactly the required functionality.

There is only one catch, you cant delete any digit but the last one. (Tested on iOS7)

But still the best solution i came across...